# How to count packets that is ECN marked at switch

Tags: networking, tcp, queue, switch-statement, congestion-control

2 hosts connect through a switch with link1, link2 correspondingly.

H1-------------------Switch---------------------H2

```
       BW1     B/K      BW2
```

Switch has buffer B (size in packets) and ECN supported. It will mark packets when buffer queue exceeds K (size in packets).

Link1 has bandwidth bw1 bigger than that of link2 bw2 and host1 sending packets continuously.

Host1 increases its sending rate by increasing Congestion Window. Because bw1>bw2 so after some time, switch has to buffer packets. If queue is approach K threshold, switch will mark packets using ECN.

Assume, at one time, host1 has Congestion Window CW1. That means from that time, in one RTT, there's maximum of CW1 packets in-flight.

So, how many packets that were marked by ECN at switch in an RTT. I want to compute the fraction.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just monitors output port of switches, and count a packet with CE bit.
use TCPDUMP, and you will obtain all of packets, and you can easily count it using regular expression filter.